# Calculator Object Oriented Design

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I am aiming to implement a calculator in an object-oriented way.

Here is the solution by using the strategy pattern.

Looking forward to some valuable comments.

```
package oopdesign.calculator;

public class AdditionStrategy implements CalculationStrategy {

    @Override
    public int calculate(int value1, int value2) {
        return value1 + value2;
    }
}


package oopdesign.calculator;

public interface CalculationStrategy {

    int calculate(int value1, int value2);
}


package oopdesign.calculator;

public class Calculator {

    public static Calculator instance = null;

    CalculationStrategy calculationStrategy;

    public void setCalculationStrategy(CalculationStrategy calculationStrategy) {
        this.calculationStrategy = calculationStrategy;
    }

    public static Calculator getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new Calculator();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public int calculate(int value1, int value2) {
       return calculationStrategy.calculate(value1, value2);
    }
}


package oopdesign.calculator;

public class CalculatorMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Calculator c = Calculator.getInstance();

        c.setCalculationStrategy(new AdditionStrategy());
        System.out.println(c.calculate(5 ,2));

        c.setCalculationStrategy(new SubtractionStrategy());
        System.out.println(c.calculate(5 ,2));

        c.setCalculationStrategy(new MultiplicationStrategy());
        System.out.println(c.calculate(5 ,2));

        c.setCalculationStrategy(new DivideStrategy());
        System.out.println(c.calculate(5 ,2));
    }
}


package oopdesign.calculator;

public class DivideStrategy implements CalculationStrategy {

    @Override
    public int calculate(int value1, int value2) {
        return value1 / value2;
    }
}


package oopdesign.calculator;

public class MultiplicationStrategy implements  CalculationStrategy{

    @Override
    public int calculate(int value1, int value2) {
        return value1 * value2;
    }
}

package oopdesign.calculator;

public class SubtractionStrategy implements CalculationStrategy {

    @Override
    public int calculate(int value1, int value2) {
        return value1 - value2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Review:

From extensibility and in pro of having the possibility of including in future versions more operations, it is a good approach. The code is very simple, and it is easy to read so it is very good your design proposal.

> The main purpose of applying design patterns is *to simplify* things, to reach the maximum level of abstraction and allow you to write meaningful code, not just repeat stuff

So, you did good.

However, there are some observations:

```java
package oopdesign.calculator;

//Singleton is a good approach for this problem
public class Calculator {

    //By default any object is null
    //Do not put it as public, you have the getInstance method
    private static Calculator instance;

    //You are limiting the operations to handle
    CalculationStrategy calculationStrategy;

    //This is not a Singleton if you allow the default constructor (its public by default)
    private Calculator() {
    }

    public void setCalculationStrategy(CalculationStrategy calculationStrategy) {
        this.calculationStrategy = calculationStrategy;
    }

    public static Calculator getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Calculator();
        return instance;
    }

    //You should think about handle the most general data type (this case double)
    public double calculate(double value1, double value2) {
       return calculationStrategy.calculate(value1, value2);
    }
}
```

```java
package oopdesign.calculator;

public class CalculatorMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Calculator c = Calculator.getInstance();

        //There is a problem with it, you need to instanciate the strategies
        //each time you need to use it
        c.setCalculationStrategy(new AdditionStrategy());
        System.out.println(c.calculate(5,2));

        //It requires space, plus you are not being efficient by storing
        //there operations (calculation strategies)
        c.setCalculationStrategy(new SubtractionStrategy());
        System.out.println(c.calculate(5,2));

        c.setCalculationStrategy(new MultiplicationStrategy());
        System.out.println(c.calculate(5,2));

        c.setCalculationStrategy(new DivideStrategy());
        System.out.println(c.calculate(5,2));
    }
}
```

#### An alternative

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Calculator {

    private static Calculator instance;

    //search in Constant time (approximately)
    private Map<String, CalculationStrategy> calculationStrategies;

    private Calculator() {
        calculationStrategies = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void addCalculationStrategy(String name, CalculationStrategy strategy) {
        calculationStrategies.put(name, strategy);
    }

    public static Calculator getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Calculator();
        return instance;
    }

    //double b... means that there may be 0 to n parameters
    //consider that there are unitary operators or functions in a calculator
    public double calculate(String name, double a, double... b) {
        return calculationStrategies.get(name).calculate(a, b);
    }
}
```

```java
package oopdesign.calculator;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator calculator = Calculator.getInstance();

        //Use a lambda instead
        calculator.addCalculationStrategy("+", (a, b) -> a + b[0]);
        //[b] is taken as an array but is a variadic parameter
        calculator.addCalculationStrategy("-", (a, b) -> a - b[0]);
        calculator.addCalculationStrategy("*", (a, b) -> a * b[0]);
        calculator.addCalculationStrategy("/", (a, b) -> a / b[0]);
        calculator.addCalculationStrategy("Abs", (a, b) -> Math.abs(a));
        calculator.addCalculationStrategy("Cos", (a, b) -> Math.cos(a));
        calculator.addCalculationStrategy("Sin", (a, b) -> Math.sin(a));

        System.out.println(calculator.calculate("+", 1, 3));
        System.out.println(calculator.calculate("-", 1, 3));
        System.out.println(calculator.calculate("*", 1, 3));
        System.out.println(calculator.calculate("/", 1, 3));
        System.out.println(calculator.calculate("Abs", -66));
        System.out.println(calculator.calculate("Cos", 75));
        System.out.println(calculator.calculate("Sin", 28));
        System.out.println(calculator.calculate("+", 666, 777));
    }
}
```

About `double b...` read this post about [Variadic function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635229/java-variadic-function-parameters), as I said, it is a way to have multiple parameters, From 0 To N parameters

Thanks for reading this answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Readability and ease of use**

I think the calculator should have simple functions : plus, minus, divide, multiple and use the strategy within the calculator.

**State**

You are setting the operation by a state in the calculator. Change state can lead to weird bugs.

For example what will happen if you call calculator.Calculate without calling setCalculationStategy?

**Singleton**

I don't understand why the calculator is a singleton? What are the benefits?

Think what will happen if you use it with multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

I like they way you thought about the problem but it has some downsides..

(The answer will only focus on the *Strategy Design Pattern* and ignores the use of the *Singleton Pattern*)

---

## Without the Strategy Pattern

Let us compare the design you provide with a different approach:

```java
class Calculator {

    int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    int substract(int a, int b) {
        return a - b;
    }

    int multiply(int a, int b) {
        return a * b;
    }

    int divide(int a, int b) {
        return a / b;
    }
}

class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Calculator c = new Calculator();

        System.out.println(c.add(5 ,2));

        System.out.println(c.substract(5 ,2));

        System.out.println(c.multiply(5 ,2));

        System.out.println(c.divide(5 ,2));
    }

}
```

The benefits of the new approach are:

- only 2 instead of 7 classes
- simply usage - no need to change the strategy for each operation

As you can see the *strategy pattern* adds to much complexity to this simple problem.

## Strategy Pattern is not made for this Use Case

The benefit of the Strategy Design Pattern is that it [enables selecting an algorithm at runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern#cite_note-1).

But *algorithm* is not meant to switch between different types of calculations; it is much more about switching between different behaviors for different types of calculators.

## A Possible Use Case

Imagine you want to sell your calculator and a potential customer has a 7-day trial period before he has to buy it. During the trial period the customer can only use `add` and `subtract`. If the customer does not buy the calculator after the trial period, no methods can be used.

For this problem presentation we could have three types of calculators:

- trail-calculator
- purchased calculator
- unpurchased calculator

### First Try without the Strategy Pattern

We could create 3 classes (to make it easy, I'll just demonstrate with `add`) and then we'll see the downside:

```java
class PurchasedCalculator {

    int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

}

class UnpurchasedCalculator {

    int add(int a, int b) {
        throw NotPurchasedExecption()
    }

}

class TrialCalculator {
    
    int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    int multiply(int a, int b) {
       throw NotPurchasedExecption();
    }
    
}
```

The downside of this approach is that we have many code duplication every where.

### Second Try with the Strategy Pattern

To avoid code duplication and the flexibility not to create a new class for each calculator type, we can use the *Strategy Pattern*:

```java
class Calculator {
    /* ... */
    
    Calculator(CalculationStrategy additionStrategy,
               CalculationStrategy substractionStrategy,
               CalculationStrategy multiplicationStrategy,
               CalculationStrategy dividitionStrategy) {
        this.additionStrategy = additionStrategy;
        this.substractionStrategy = substractionStrategy;
        this.multiplicationStrategy = multiplicationStrategy;
        this.divideStrategy = divideStrategy;
    }

    int add(int a, int b) {
        return additionStrategy.calculate(a, b);
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

We can easy create different calculator types:

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        Calculator trial = new Calculator(new AdditionStrategy(), 
                                          new SubstractionStrategy(),
                                          new NotPurchasedStrategy(),
                                          new NotPurchasedStrategy());

        Calculator purchased = new Calculator(new AdditionStrategy(), 
                                              new SubstractionStrategy(),
                                              new MultiplicationStrategy(),
                                              new DividitionStrategy());

        Calculator unpurchased = new Calculator(new NotPurchasedStrategy(), 
                                                new NotPurchasedStrategy(),
                                                new NotPurchasedStrategy(),
                                                new NotPurchasedStrategy());

    }

}
```

Or modify the behavior at runtime - for instance the customer did not pay his subscription:

```java
Calculator purchased = new Calculator(new AdditionStrategy(), 
                                      new SubstractionStrategy(),
                                      new MultiplicationStrategy(),
                                      new DividitionStrategy());

purchased.setAdditionStrategy(new NotPurchasedStrategy());
/*...*/
```

Answer (score 1):

What about designing it in such a way that more operations can be added later and different calculation logic can be implemented by extending the base class.

````
public class TestCalculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //list of operator
        List<Operator> operatorList = new LinkedList<>();
        operatorList.add(new Add());
        operatorList.add(new Multiply());

        //operator precedence, Assuming highest precedence operator is at lower index
        List<Character> operatorPrecedence = new ArrayList<>();
        operatorPrecedence.add('*');
        operatorPrecedence.add('+');

        // initialise SimpleExpressionCalculator
        ExpressionCalculator expressionCalculator = new SimpleExpressionCalculator(operatorList,operatorPrecedence);
        System.out.println(expressionCalculator.calculate("2 + 5 * 3 * 2 + 2"));
    }
}

interface Calculator {
    Double calculate(String expression);
}

class SimpleExpressionCalculator implements Calculator {
    Map<Character,Operator> operatorMap;
    List<Character> operatorPrecedence;

    public SimpleExpressionCalculator(List<Operator> operators,List<Character> operatorPrecedence ) {
        operatorMap = new HashMap<>();
        for(Operator o : operators) {
            operatorMap.put(o.getSymbol(),o);
        }
        this.operatorPrecedence = operatorPrecedence;
    }

    @Override
    public Double calculate(String expression) {
        // logic to parse the expression and return result
        return 0.0;
    }
}

interface Operator {
    public Double operate(Double d1, Double d2);
    public Character getSymbol();
}

class Add implements Operator {
    @Override
    public Double operate(Double d1, Double d2) {
        return d1 + d2;
    }

    @Override
    public Character getSymbol() {
        return '+';
    }
}


class Multiply implements Operator {
    @Override
    public Double operate(Double d1, Double d2) {
        return d1 * d2;
    }

    @Override
    public Character getSymbol() {
        return '*';
    }
}
```
````